# SQL orderby if statement if one field is empty use the other one

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, multiple-tables

I have a query with combination of two table and connected with ID:

First table is `category`

```
ID|code|parent
1 |cd01|0
2 |cd02|0
3 |cd03|0
```

and the second table is `category_description`

```
ID|name |lang_id
1 |cat01|1
1 |cat01|2
1 |cat01|3
2 |cat02|2
2 |cat02|3
3 |cat03|1
3 |cat03|2
```

and now there is an instance that category has no entry in `category_description` with `lang_id = 1` so when I list as grid, I use code instead of name and I want to order by is statement that when name is not set I will use the code.

```
|  ID  | Name         |
------------------------ 
|  1   | cat01 - cd01 |
|  2   | cd02         |
|  3   | cat03 - cd03 |
```

Code:

```
SELECT c.code, cd.name  
FROM category c, category_description cd 
WHERE cd.ID = c.ID 
GROUP BY cd.ID 
ORDER BY
```

if cd.name is not set use c.code

Any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show your query?

Comment: what is lang_id? and what is logic behind your output? why `cat01` displayed with `id` (**1**) two times in output?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: your sql statement doesn't match your output. Should not be select "*"